# How to specify UV channels for different maps in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to specify which set of UVs should be used for different maps (textures)?

Can you specify which UVs should be used for each texture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no interface for specifying UV channels for standard materials in current revision of three.js (r78). Lambert / Phong / Standard materials use second channel (uv2) for lightMap and aoMap. Yet it is possible to make your own materials with custom uv channels from standard materials.

Such material could be constructed this way:

1. Make your vertex and fragment shaders. Standard three.js materials are constructed using chunks (c-style preprocessor **#include** directives) which could be replaced with your code. For example, among [three.js standard shaders](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib) there are MeshPhongMaterial [vertex](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_vert.glsl) and [fragment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshphong_frag.glsl) shaders. Fragment shader has such row: `#include <lights_template>`. Corresponding file [lights_template.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_template.glsl) could be found in [chunks directory](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk). This file contains following code:

   ```
   #ifdef USE_LIGHTMAP
       vec3 lightMapIrradiance = texture2D( lightMap, vUv2 ).xyz * lightMapIntensity;
       // more code here
   #endif
   ```

   Changing `vUv2` in this texture lookup with affect what coords will be used for lightMap. If you need additional uv sets you could pass them through vertex shader as varyings just as vUv and vUv2.
   This way desired shaders could be obtained by copy-pasting original three.js shaders into your source code and a bit of editing.
2. Make you uniforms object. For this [THREE.UniformsLib](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/UniformsLib.js) could be helpful. Also you could get uniform from existing material via [THREE.UniformsUtils.clone()](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/UniformsUtils.js).
3. Add defines which you need for material in front of your vertex and fragment shaders (`fragmentShader = '#define USE_LIGHTMAP\n' + fragmentShader;`).
4. Create your material using [THREE.RawShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/RawShaderMaterial). [THREE.ShaderMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Materials/ShaderMaterial) without prepending defines should work too.

Also if you need simple material it could be faster to ignore chunks and write desired shader from scratch.